# Capture HDMI signal and process it in a programming language

Tags: video, video-capture, hdmi

I want to send the HDMI signal from my Playstation 4 to my computer, and process it live in a programming language. The fps dosn't really need to be faster than 10 fps, and the quality isn't that important either. I am currently running Windows 10, but I am also comfortable with running Linux, and I'm not bound to any specific programming language.

So my question is, does it exist some sort of HDMI Capture Card, that can be used with a programming language, and isn't too expensive? Like a HDMI Capture Card that is compatible with Python (or any other language), so that I could edit the video stream frame by frame.

I have been searching the internett for a way to do this, but can't really get a clue on which card that will work with a programming langugae, and I don't want to waste my money buying the wrong card.

Thanks for any answer.

(Sorry if my english isn't perfect)

Comment: One way is to use Blackmagic capturing devices. Same here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49543935/merge-2-image-outputs-hdmi-dvi-vga-or-other-on-one-screen/49579614#49579614

Answer (score -1):

There is one type of equipment may suit for you.

It capture the HDMI input and convert this into UVC (usb3.0) connect to PC.
So sdk is provided for further development, or using obs (open broadcast) support 1080P/60HZ.

You can search this kind of card/box.
Key words: USB3.0 HDMI SDI capture

Answer (score -1):

Here's a posting describing my capture-device and my experience with it so far:
https://superuser.com/questions/1725293